# How to get response code or status from Microsoft Graph remove member API?

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm using Graph API remove member API to delete a member from group. After successful deletion I'm not getting any kind of response from the api.

```
export async function removeGroupMember(accessToken, groupId, memberId) {
  const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);
  client
    .api("/groups/" + groupId + "/members/" + memberId + "/$ref")
    .delete()
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);    //undefined
      console.log(res.status);   //undefined
    });
}
```

I read in docs that it won't return any response body, but it will return a response code 204 on successful deletion. How can I get the response code?

Now the above code is doing the job, I'm able to remove a member using the above code, I verified in the Azure portal. But I need some kind of response in Frontend to let the user know that member is removed. For error handling purpose. I'm not sure if this is a Javascript question or Graph API, Azure AD question.

Comment: Did you try .api("...").responseType(ResponseType.RAW).delete().then((res)=>{...} ? but I'm not sure if it will work for delete which doesn't return any response body.

Comment: I'm not aware of this method Can you please tell me how to use it in my code context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the raw response:

```
export async function removeGroupMember(accessToken, groupId, memberId) {
  const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);
  client
    .api("/groups/" + groupId + "/members/" + memberId + "/$ref")
    .delete()
    .responseType(MicrosoftGraph.ResponseType.RAW)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.status);
    });
}
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/GettingRawResponse.md)

I'm not sure if it will work for delete which doesn't return any response body

Comment: This worked dude. Thanks. Just to clarify 'MicrosoftGraph' in the responseType is the Microsoft Graph client which I got using `var MicrosoftGraph = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");`

Comment: @dharanikumar Great